# Java GUI shows up blank

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jframe, jpanel

So I'm trying to create my first GUI in Java but it's coming up blank. As far as I can see I've done everything correct, but of course since it's just blank I'm obviously doing something wrong.
I've got a mainclass and a class for the JFrame and all its contents.
I'm not getting any errors except for the public class MainFrame giving me "The serializable class MainFrame does not declare a static final serialVersionUID field of type long".

```
package main;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

import gui.MainFrame;

public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {

     SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

         public void run() 
             MainFrame frame = new MainFrame();

             frame.setTitle("GUI");

             frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

             frame.setSize(800, 400);

             frame.setVisible(true);

        }
     });
 }

}
```

.

```
package gui;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class MainFrame extends JFrame {

 private JButton button;
 private Container cont;

 public MainFrame(){
     Container cont = new Container();

     setLayout(new BorderLayout());

     JPanel panel = new JPanel();
     panel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

     JButton button = new JButton("Change Color");

     panel.add(button, BorderLayout.CENTER);

     cont.add(panel, BorderLayout.CENTER);

     cont.setBackground(Color.GREEN);

     button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

         public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
             cont.setBackground(Color.CYAN);

         }
     });

 }
}
```

Comment: You might try adding something to your frame

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Forgot about adding component to frame:

```
panel.add(cont);
```

Answer (score 3):

You didn't add `Container cont` to the frame.

Comment: yes, you need to `panel.add(cont);`